# Washed out/over saturated colors on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, intel, colors

I have an Acer Aspire S5-371T Laptop than I recently bought and I have it dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, however I've noticed something strange with the colors in Ubuntu. I'm not the best at describing things but I believe the colors are either washed out or over saturated. Here is a side-by-side comparison of the same video in Windows 10 and Ubuntu (Note: My editing skills are really bad, ignore the fact that the windows screenshot looks smaller)

[image: Windows 10 & Ubuntu Screen Comparison]

I've tried multiple things, but nothing seems to work/fix it. The last thing I tried was use Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux, but it gave some errors

[image: Intel Graphics Tool Errors]

Despite what it sounds like, I have mesa 17.0.7 already and it wants mesa 12.0.6. I don't even know if this is what I should be doing.

Any ideas on how to get my colors in Ubuntu to look normal would be appreciated.

Note: The color effect shows up in screenshots and applies to external monitors that I plug in. Also I think my previous laptop (Dell Inspiron 1525) had the same issue, but it was only really noticeable in screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works on 16.04 (as I'm using Pop_OS 20.04), but try changing the contrast of the display:

```
xgamma -gamma 0.95
```

Ranges go from 0 to 1, 0 being very dark, 1 being 'default'. I've found 0.95 to be closer to what I expect/had seen on windows.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have that laptop or an Ubuntu 16.04 installation so I can't test that, but thank you anyways. I'll keep this in mind for future Linux installs.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't there for you 3 years ago when you needed me most!

Comment: Pop is of topic here.