# Why are my screen colours more vivid using Windows10 than Ubuntu?

Tags: screen, colors

I'm duel booting a laptop and as I mentioned in the title, the colours are more vivid and whites more white when I'm booted into Windows vs Ubuntu. Any reason why that would be and what can be done? Cheers for reading.

Comment: There should be an option for Device Colour Profiles in system settings. Maybe you can try another profile.

Comment: Also, did you check that the luminosity is maximal in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Related: [Washed out/over saturated colors on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956906/washed-out-over-saturated-colors-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Muru, there are no colour profiles in the settings, only Orientation, Resolution, Refresh rate and Night light.

Comment: Tobias, I don't no what luminosity is. Do you mean screen brightness? Yes It's 100% Thanks for the reply.